# How to run ExtJS 6 application in eclipse with tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, extjs6

I have generated Extjs6 app by sencha cmd, I able to run the app by sencha cmd but when I try to copy the same app into eclipse it takes so much time to build and it gives an error after some time.

Comment: Bit old but could help http://yakovfain.com/2013/04/24/configuring-eclipse-with-apache-tomcat-and-ext-js/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with bring an ExtJS application into Eclipse is that Eclipse will try to parse all of the ExtJs source code as well. This gets quite time-consuming, and reduces the effectiveness of things such as JavaScript warnings.

One alternative is create a [Sencha workspace](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/workspaces.html) first, and then create applications inside the workspace. You can then import the application without including the entire ExtJS library.

You can then "deploy" the workspace to a Tomcat server in Eclipse by adding the workspace as an external web directory